# Creating multiple nodes using device_create()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to write a simple character device driver for Linux. I want to create multiple node using the function `device_create()`. So I have used different Minor numbers and same major number.

```
device_create(cls, NULL, MKDEV(MAJOR(first),0), NULL, "sou_dev1");

device_create(cls1, NULL, MKDEV(MAJOR(first),1), NULL, "sou_dev2");
```

The cls and cls1 are struct class type variable and are return value of `class_create()`.
When I make the .ko file and insert it to kernel using "insmod" command, then only one node is created in /dev/ directory, i.e, sou_dev1.

What shall I do to create both sou_dev1 and sou_dev2

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use dynamic allocation always. I would suggest to use `misc_register()` and `misc_unregister()` which is more straight forward. Refer to headers [linux/miscdevice.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/miscdevice.h). Here is an some sample code.

```
/*implemented these functions*/
const struct file_operations chr_fops = {
        .write   = chr_write,    
        .read    = chr_read,
        .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
};

static struct miscdevice my_dev1 = {
        .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
        .name = "/dev/MYDEVNAME1",
        .fops = &chr_fops
};

static struct miscdevice my_dev2 = {
        .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
        .name = "/dev/MYDEVNAME2",
        .fops = &chr_fops
};

int init_module(void)
{
        int ret;

        ret = misc_register(&my_dev1);
        if (ret != 0) {
                pr_err("misc_register() failed");
                return ret;
        }

        pr_info("device registered: %s\n", "/dev/MYDEVNAME1");

        ret = misc_register(&my_dev2);
        if (ret != 0) {
                pr_err("misc_register() failed");
                return ret;
        }

        pr_info("device registered: %s\n", "/dev/MYDEVNAME2");

        return ret;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{

        do_cleanup_func();

        misc_deregister(&my_dev);

        pr_info("device unregistered\n");
}
```